# How can I make my Gmail searches faster?

Tags: gmail, search

When I first signed up with Gmail, I was impressed by how fast I could search through my email. Now even simple single-keyword searches can take 5-10 seconds. Perhaps this is related to having over 70,000 conversations archived - but I don't want to delete them if I can avoid it. Are there any tricks to speeding up search time in Gmail?

Comment: This question was bumped by an answer that was deleted for being flagged as spam. I’m voting to close this question because this question looks to be obsolete. After all, the context has changed too much due to the evolution of the technology related to user devices, networking, the ISP market offering, the changes done to Gmail and web browsers and that nowadays, many users have moved from desktop to mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried searching in another browser/computer? Sometimes clearing cache of the web browser helps this.

Comment: It's about the same on any computer I try it on, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

I find that searching for mails that address directly to me is quicker, since I subscribe to a bunch of mailing lists I normally don't need to search those. In the search field I add a `to:me`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the various search operators to narrow down the search. You'll probably have some idea who the e-mail was from or to, for example.